# Hiding inside mount cellular blinds in shallow window

Tags: windows, trim, blinds

I've got some inside mount cellular shades that are about 2" thick. My current windows are very shallow as they are newer windows installed in an older home. All told to the drywall there's only about 1/2 inch from the forward most part of the window to the drywall. See here [image: existing window 1] and [image: existing window 2] and [image: existing window 3]

Other rooms in our house we've gone with a craftsman style casing and baseboard, and would like to continue it in here. However I was trying to come up with a way to keep the edges of the blinds fully hidden from the side view. With 1-1/2 inch thick casing the front of the blinds are hidden perfectly though the trim may look a little strange being that extra 3/4" thick. Wondering if anyone has any ideas to deal with this? Or what kind of detail I could add to the trim package to make the extra thickness look more cohesive.

[image: Trim Idea]

Maybe I could add that thin strip to maybe the inside and outside profile of a standard 1x4 vertical casing to add some thickness to the inside that would allow me to hide the blinds while keeping it looking somewhat decent maybe like this?
[image: Trim Idea 2]

kind of like the stop at the bottom of the header frieze in the WindsorOne version

[image: WinsorTrimPack]

Just not sure what will look good or if going with thicker casing will ever look good. opinions, other options? Thanks

Comment: Buy thinner blinds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came up with a decent solution.  I'm going to frame the window with a shaker style recessed panel column.

[image: simple column]

I'll take a 1x4 and make it 3x thickness by attaching 2 layers of 1x material around the edges. Then take 1/4" to 1/2" material and create the raised part of the panels.  The rest of the header will stay the same as normal craftsman header maybe with an extra piece of moulding or two to make it blend in better with the columns.